# Unable to install SendGrid Extension

Tags: macos, azure, azure-functions

I have two sendgrid azure functions that work some days ago but today, when I was testing my application, I see that my functions are not working anymore because any method for sendgrid are not available.

So i tried to install again the extension for my functions and I get this error :

[image]

Anybody have informations about that ?

Comment: Is this with the v2 Preview runtime? It could be because [these recent changes](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94). Are you installing the extension via Portal, or using Visual Studio? Try updating to the latest version of the extension.

Comment: Yeap is V2 Preview. And it's from the portal. In my dev machine (macOS), it's working well.

Comment: @DavidEbbo if youwant some points, add an answer. you github link save my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were recent (intentional) breaking changes in the v2 Preview runtime. To fix this, you will need to update to the latest version of the SendGrid extension.

More details available on https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94.